# Overriding page template using page_template filter

Tags: page-template

I tried

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'single_page_template' );

function single_page_template( $template )
  {
      if ( is_singular( 'dwqa-question' ) ) {

          $template =  get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . page-question.php;
      }
      return $template;
  }
```

now, if I will out put  `echo get_page_template();`  I am getting

`/var/www/html/my-site/wp-content/themes/theme-child/page-question.php`

but modifying the page-question.php file not effecting the output ,adding some text to this template like

`get_header(); ?>zzzzzzzzz`

not getting out put. page.php is assign to single question page using `template_include` hook is this because of that , but if yes echoing `get_page_template()` should also give page.php tempalte path as output .

Just modified page.php like

`get_header(); ?>aaaa`

and `aaaa` is appearing on page .

How I should override it ??  please let me know if I should provide any other detail ?

Comment: Can you provide more details? such as the custom post type slug, is dwqa-question the post type slug in question? if so you can have a custom template specific to this post type by having single-posttypeslug.php in your theme folder

Comment: @AhmedElmahdy creating a single-dwqa-question.php will not work as the plugin has used template_include hook to force it use page.php and I  am trying to override that .

Comment: Maybe they're using a hook with higher priority that's why it overrides yours?

Comment: @AhmedElmahdy but get_page_template() function is displaying my template as I have mentioned in question .

Comment: I think this is more of a question for the [DW Question & Answer](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/dw-question-answer) forum than here, because you're asking about overriding that plugin's particular implementation of determining the template to use, and not about the standard WordPress implementation.

Comment: @DaveRomsey sorry, Dave but page_template hook unable to override a template , how it becomes DW Question and Answer plugin specific ? It may happen on any other occasion, I am talking about a DW QA hook .

Answer (score 7):

From your question, it seems you're trying to override the single template of a custom post type. If so, the filter you want to use is `single_template` and not `page_template`:

```
function single_page_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'dwqa-question') {
        $single_template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/page-question.php';
    }

    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'single_page_template' );
```

I once had this issue and it was driving me crazy, until I found the filter on the WordPress Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template

Comment: Hi, `'/' . page-question.php` will most probably crash your website.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Theme Handbook (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use), "Do not use `page-` as a prefix, as WordPress will interpret the file as a specialized template, meant to apply to only one page on your site."

So - try renaming `page-question.php` something like `tpl-question.php` (tpl is a common prefix, short for template).

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but it does not solved the problem facing same situation.

Comment: You could try giving your function a higher priority - `add_filter( 'page_template', 'single_page_template', 100 );`

Comment: sorry friend, but I have already tried even 9999 and it did not worked .

Answer (score 1):

You mispelled the "page-question.php" portion of code, it must be included in quotes:

```
$template =  get_stylesheet_directory() . '/page-question.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to implement flush of the rewrite rules function.

```
    flush_rewrite_rules();
```

You are free to use the alternative way,

```
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules( true );
```